# Array not get data for particular key

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

Response array like this

```
 NewDataSet =     {
        Table =         (
                        {
                City =             {
                    text = "\nThiruvananthapuram";
                };
                Country =             {
                    text = "\n\nIndia";
                };
                text = "\n";
            },
                    {
                City =             {
                    text = "\nVellore";
                };
                Country =             {
                    text = "\n\nIndia";
                };
                text = "\n";
            }
        );
        text = "\n";
```

I have write this code..

```
xmlDictionary = [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLString:xmlResultString error:nil];

    NSLog(@"%@",xmlDictionary);



    NSLog(@"%@",xmlDictionary);

    NSArray * responseArr = xmlDictionary[@"NewDataSet"];

    NSLog(@"%@",responseArr);


    for(NSDictionary * dic in responseArr)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",dic);

        //[array1 addObject:[dic valueForKey:@"City"]];

        [array1 addObject:[[dic valueForKey:@"City"] valueForKey:@"text"]];

    }
```

but not get the data. in array1. please help me out this thanks in advance.

**Problem is i will not get the value in NSDictionary.**

Error log is

**this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key City.'**

Comment: are you getting data in responseArr?

Comment: yes get data in Responsearray..

Comment: just print that data.....show me that data..

Comment: have you allocated the array1 anywhere..it is important to alloc and init it?

Comment: ya i have done this is viewDidLoad()..

Comment: Looking nested dictionary... trace dictionary step by step. Don't confuse my friend.

Comment: In your "for" statement, just print the value of "dic". Then you will see what each object contains. Probably the object is wrong or the object is not a dictionary. Where does the ");" come from? you are not opening it anywhere, please provide the whole code around the problem.

Comment: try this.  [array1 addObject:[[dic valueForKey:@"City"] valueForKey:@"text"]];.. now are you getting??please let me know..

Comment: Can you post a more complete example please.  I don't see where `array1` is created and that example data doesn't look complete either.

Comment: It would be more readable if you can post the log of `responseArray` in JSON format.

Comment: no this is also not working...

Comment: no not json format it's xml format data @Anupdas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my Solution problem is i will not get the direct City key. Because City key is under the  `NewDataSet  & Table`

so first you go to the NewDataSet and then Table key then finally you get the City key.

Now get array data from Dictionary Like

```
NSArray * City=[[NSArray alloc]init];

City=[[[xmlDictionary valueForKey:@"NewDataSet"] valueForKey:@"Table"] valueForKey:@"City"];

NSLog(@"%@",City);
```

pass multiple keys inside key this is the solution.

Answer (score -1):

It seems you haven't allocated array1 anywhere,

Your solution goes here:

```
   array1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

   for(NSDictionary * dic in responseArr)
    {
        [array1 addObject:[dic valueForKey:@"City"]];
    }
    NSLog(@"array1 >> %@",array1);
```

If you have already allocated array1, then please try to log the value for `[dic valueForKey:@"City"]`.

Comment: yeah I know this is not the complete solution. But I will guide you step by step. So please let me know are you getting the value in dic? If yes, what value?

Comment: And what happens id `dic` doesn't contain a "City" key?

Answer (score -1):

```
        array1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        for(NSDictionary * dic in responseArr)
        {

            [array1 addObject:[dic objectForKey:@"City"]];
        }

        NSLog(@"array1 >> %@",array1);
```

Try this

Comment: Start to describe answer for better practice and learning for other.

Comment: And what happens id `dic` doesn't contain a "City" key?

Comment: @JitendraDeore:can u pls print the exact log of your data

Answer (score -1):

try this code...

```
   for(int i =0;i<[responseArr count];i++)
   {

     NSString *str = [[responseArr objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"City"];
     [array1 addObject:str];
  }
```

let me know it is working or not!!!

Happy Coding!!!

Comment: -[__NSDictionaryM objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xfe61d90' this error when i tried your code..

Comment: you have not displayed proper data...there are some missing brackets.please display proper data with all brackets...